# Yii2 Nav widget : active item

Tags: yii2, nav

I have `Nav` with items:

```
[
    'label' => 'All',
    'url' => ['project/index'],
],
[
    'label' => 'Done',
    'url' => ['project/index', 'assigned' => 'done'],
],
```

But both of them have an `active` class when I go to project/index&assigned=done. How can I force to attach this class only if item's `url` is strictly equal to `$route` value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Nav` widget will make an item active when its route and parameters match [`$route`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-bootstrap-nav.html#$route-detail) (if not set, it will use the route of the current request) and [`$params`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-bootstrap-nav.html#$params-detail) (if not set, it will use $_GET).

Your first item will always be active if the route is `project/index` (take a look [here](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap/blob/2.0.6/Nav.php#L273)).

You should try this for example :

```
[
    'label' => 'All',
    'url' => ['project/index', 'assigned' => 'not-done'],
],
[
    'label' => 'Done',
    'url' => ['project/index', 'assigned' => 'done'],
],
```

Read more about [how `Nav` widget set an item active or not](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-bootstrap-nav.html#isItemActive()-detail).

Comment: Thank you for links. They are useful.